# How to use sharepoint access to membership information on office365

Tags: sharepoint, oauth

Sorry, my English is weak, only use diagrams to describe my problem.

In the following figure, as shown, I want to log in using microsoftonline.com (as A) which account settings on my own server (as B). In my server (as B) which can obtain microsoftonline.com (as A) the account information.

How to achieve?

PS:I was able to get to the token social api implementation of access when an unauthorized error.

Looking for help and guidance of the experts. Thank you first.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yOEw.png

Answer (score 0):

keep trying after their own, and finally solve this problem, to the point code to facilitate the needs of others it.

developed using csom

important : rUri need to fill true, otherwise an error will occur 400...

```
  string authCode = Request.QueryString["code"];
  string error = Request.QueryString["error"];
  if (authCode == "" || "access_denied" == error)
  {
      Response.Write("I'm sorry you do not have the right to access this site, please contact the system administrator authorization");
      Response.End();
  }
  Uri rUri = new Uri("You fill out an application API Redirect address as https://***/RedirectAccept.aspx");
  string o365Site = "You need an authorized user's site collection as https://***.sharepoint.com/";

  using (ClientContext context = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAuthorizationCode(
                                   o365Site, 
                                   "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", 
                                   authCode, 
                                   TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(new Uri(o365Site)), 
                                   rUri)) {
    //
    Web web = context.Web;
    //          
    context.Load(web.CurrentUser);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    Response.Write("context.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName" + " : " + context.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName + "<br/>");
    ......
```